# How can I pass an async function to lng fetching the users language from db?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I want to either pass the users language by fetching it from the db if logged in or accessing the device language. I seem to be able to pass a function to lng, but cannot pass any async function or make any asynchronous api requests as Im getting an error. How can I do that?

```
i18next.init({
  lng: () => { //get an error
   return axios.get('user_lang')
  }, 
  lng: async () => { //using async leads to same error
    await ...
  },
  debug: true,
  fallbackLng: Localization.locale.substr(0, 2),
  resources: {
    en: {
      translation: {
        "key": "hello world"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

the error im getting is:

> undefined is not a function (near '...codes.forEach...')

I cannot find any other property besides lng that would let me set the users language.

Comment: Please add the relevant code parts. The part where the error occurs seems to be missing.

Comment: I18next.init options lng property looks like it takes a string.

Comment: the error comes when I add either an async function or make some api request inside function while function is a prop of lng

Comment: yes it does take a string, but passing a function that returns a string seems fine too but i cant seem to be able to make api requests inside so i wonder how can i set users language by fetching it from db